# iPhone App: images for retina display not showing

Tags: iphone, ios4, retina-display

In my iPhone app I'm including high resolution image with naming convention imagename@2x.png, but it is not showing higher resolution images for retina display.

What could be wrong?

Comment: How are you loading the images?

Comment: Are you sure the "imagename" part is exactly the same for the images? Are they in the same folder/place?

Comment: First, iOS is caseSensitive. So check whether the filenames have the correct case. Then, check whether the `@2x` images are each exactly twice as large (width and height) as their non-`@2x` versions.

Comment: @ DarkDust  Thanks in my case problem was case Sensitivity

Comment: @Prerak: Are you testing it on iPhone 4? Because testing for retina displaay requires iPhone 4.

Comment: This question can be closed as "typo/unrepro", since the accepted answer is a very general answer that is not specific to this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case problem was case Sensitivity of @2x

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the images programmality try to use:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Make sure you are on a project that supports the retina display.

[]'s